# print each number from the array and the times it has been repeated

Tags: java

I have an array containing the below nos: 
1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1
I need to print each number from the array and the times it has been repeated in the array.
I am receiving an error while running the below program "i cannot be resolved to a variable".

---

```
public class PrintNosandRepeatation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = new int[] {1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};
        for (int i=0; i< a.length; i++);
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Please let me know where i am going wrong..

Answer (score 4):

Delete the `;` after the `if` condition:

```
for (int i=0; i< a.length; i++);
                               ^------------- delete this
```

**Why?** Because it declares an empty statement, so the `for` body will be empty. Therefore when you try to use variable `i`, it is actually out of the block it was declared in (a block is delimited by `{ }`).

Comment: There lied the mistake.. Resolved now.. Can you also tell me how do i find the repetitive nos.say i wanna display"1- repeated 3 times" etc..

Comment: That should be a separate question, but be sure you show some effort while asking (what you have tried, where you are having problems).

Answer (score 0):

int a[]= {1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};

```
    int i, j;
    System.out.println("Repeated Elements are :");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: printing a counter for every repetition will be more cleaner.